# Django NoReverseMatch at /register

Tags: django

I'm attempting to enable users to register on my Django based website; however I am running into the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /register
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I am struggling to see what needs to be changed below, I feel that I have tried tweaking everything to get it working, but nothing seems to. I am using a namespace "Flightfinder" for my application, not sure if this has something to do with it?

**Full Error:**

```
NoReverseMatch at /register
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/register
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Final Project/finalproject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Final Project/finalproject/.venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Final Project/finalproject',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Final '
 'Project/finalproject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 11 Nov 2020 20:32:27 +0000
```

**Layout Template:**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'flightfinder/styles.css' %}">

    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'flightfinder/main.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}Flight Finder{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'Flightfinder:index' %}">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TRBkPBZ/Flight-Finder-removebg-preview.png" width="166" height="42" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="{% url 'Flightfinder:index' %}">Flights <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Hotels</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Car Hire</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'Flightfinder:logout' %}">Log Out</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'Flightfinder:login' %}">Log In</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'Flightfinder:register' %}">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**Views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, 'flightfinder/register.html', {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, 'flightfinder/register.html', {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, 'flightfinder/register.html')
```

**Urls.py - Main:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('flightfinder.urls', namespace='Flightfinder')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Urls.py - App:**

```
app_name = 'flightfinder'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path('origin_airport_search/', views.origin_airport_search, name='origin_airport_search')
]
```

Thank you in advance for having a look into this for me, very much appreciated!

Comment: It is `{% url 'flightfinder:register' %}` (so with *lowercase* `f`), not `{% url 'Flightfinder:register' %}`. The same holds for all other `{% url ... %}` template tags.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem - thank you for your response. I'm having difficulty accessing the page by manually visiting the URL. I changed all of the links to lowercase just to validate that it wasn't the issue and can unfortunately confirm that it persists.

Comment: well the problem is (very) likely in the template you render in the `register` view. There it there is a `{% url ... register %}` that has a certain issue. For example the wrong namespace, no namespace, etc.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, I've resolved the problem now. There was a link without the namespace attached to it within the register view. I wasn't looking into that view as thought there was an issue elsewhere. Appreciate your assistance!